# 60 degrees angled text in HTML / HTML5 ( in scriptable format )

Tags: javascript, html, css

One of the outputs from my software is written in to html5 format. It involves color-coding a particular column of text (depending on position chosen by user) and I have implemented this using monospace font so as to keep text alignment which is of primary requirement. Such highlighted column should be labelled so as to easily track them.

Currently I am doing this by displaying label text (shown in red color) vertically but as you could see it is not easily readable (especially true when labels are right next to each other). It will be 1000x better if I could show the label in an angled manner -preferably at 60 degrees. It cannot be hard-coded as the solution needs to scripting compatible. Is there a way to do it in a way that can be scripted? Thanks in advance!!

**Expected Output:**
[image]

**Screenshot of current output:**
[image: Current]

**Current HTML code:**

```
<!doctype html>
<HEAD>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="CONTENT-TYPE" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <STYLE>
        * {
            font-family:"Lucida Sans Typewriter", "Lucida Console", Monaco, "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", monospace;
            font-size: 13px;
        }
        vert {
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
            color: red;
        }   
    </STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY LANG="en-US" DIR="LTR">
<PRE CLASS="western">
                                <vert>2<br />1<br /></vert>        <vert>3<br />0<br /></vert> <vert>3<br />2<br /></vert>           <vert>4<br />4<br /></vert>           <vert>5<br />6<br /></vert>    
Line1       MSLLNVPAGKDLPEDIYVVI<strong><span style="background-color: #42DB33">E</span></strong>IPANADPI<strong><span style="background-color: #42DB33">K</span></strong>Y<strong><span style="background-color: #42DB33">E</span></strong>IDKESGALFVD<strong><span style="background-color: #42DB33">R</span></strong>FMSTAMFYPCN<strong><span style="background-color: #42DB33">Y</span></strong>GYIN   60
Line2       MNIKEIPIGNNPPEDVNVII<strong><span style="background-color: #42DB33">E</span></strong>VPVDSQPV<strong><span style="background-color: #42DB33">K</span></strong>Y<strong><span style="background-color: #42DB33">E</span></strong>MDKKSGSLFVD<strong><span style="background-color: #42DB33">R</span></strong>FISTSMVYPGN<strong><span style="background-color: #42DB33">Y</span></strong>GFIP   60
Line3       -MFIDKIKAKANNDEINVII<strong><span style="background-color: #42DB33">E</span></strong>IPMNIGPI<strong><span style="background-color: #42DB33">K</span></strong>Y<strong><span style="background-color: #42DB33">E</span></strong>FDKESGAVFVD<strong><span style="background-color: #42DB33">R</span></strong>FMQTTMSYPCN<strong><span style="background-color: #42DB33">Y</span></strong>GFIP   59
Line4       -MFIDKIKAKANNDEINVII<strong><span style="background-color: #42DB33">E</span></strong>IPMNSGPI<strong><span style="background-color: #42DB33">K</span></strong>Y<strong><span style="background-color: #42DB33">E</span></strong>FDKESGAVFVD<strong><span style="background-color: #42DB33">R</span></strong>FMQTTMSYPCN<strong><span style="background-color: #42DB33">Y</span></strong>GFIP   59

</PRE>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Edit 1: Updated with expected output picture. And code updated per @FelipeAls suggestion on removing `font` and styling with `css` instead.

Comment: Could you please share the screenshot of desired output as well. Since this all is related to presentation of data - better to have the final look & feel.

Comment: Written from bottom-left corner to top right corner I guess. OP `font` element is an HTML abomination from XXth century and `vert` doesn't exist. You could replace those by a class on a element `a.vert` and should style it in CSS: `.vert { color: red; }`

Comment: @FelipeAls, Vijay - I have updated the post as per your suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

**You can have completely scripted control using html5 canvas:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
  var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  offsetX=BB.left;
  offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }


var PI=Math.PI;
var leftMargin=25;
var topMargin=75;
var lineWidth=25;
var highlightMargin=topMargin-25;

var lines=[];
lines.push('we had everything before us');
lines.push('we had nothing before us');
lines.push('we were all going direct to Heaven');
lines.push('we were all going direct the other way');

var font='18px courier';
ctx.font=font;

var charWidth=ctx.measureText('w').width;

drawText();

highlight(13);
highlight(21);
highlight(22);

function highlight(column){

  var x=leftMargin+(column-1)*charWidth;

  // draw the highlight bar at the current mouseX
  ctx.globalAlpha=.25;
  ctx.fillStyle='gold';
  ctx.fillRect(x,highlightMargin,charWidth,topMargin+lines.length*lineWidth);
  ctx.globalAlpha=1.00;

  // display the tilted character position
  ctx.font='9px arial';
  ctx.fillStyle='red';
  ctx.textAlign='center';
  ctx.translate(x+charWidth/2,highlightMargin);
  ctx.rotate(-PI/4);
  ctx.fillText(column,0,0);
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);

}


function drawText(){
  // draw the lines[] of text
  ctx.textAlign='left';
  ctx.font=font;
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  ctx.fillStyle='black';
  for(var i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
    ctx.fillText(lines[i],leftMargin,topMargin+i*lineWidth);
  }
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=450 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: @markE- This is beautiful but is there a way to number/label just the columns I am interested in? Static result is sufficient if it has label on top of highlighted column. Thanks!

Comment: Sure! I've edited my answer to show how to select one or more columns as simple as: `highlight(21)`. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

You can angle the labels with css

```
vert {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}
```

Though a screenshot would be preferred to be able to match correctly.

**Update:**

if you take the 
 out from in between each digit then you can use `rotate(-45deg)` that will get what you want for angling the text.

Comment: Ideally it has to treat even two or three digit number as a single digit so that I can seat it right on top of that column using automated scripting. Using your current suggestion would do it otherwise. I have updated with expected output picture. Thanks!

Comment: Your updated answer seems to be incomplete. If you meant removing `break` tag, such a change does rotate them but alignment becomes an issue. For example, if you have adjacent columns highlighted, say columns 31,32 and 33, they don't align properly just above corresponding columns.